# Unix-to-Unix Encoding (Uuencoding)

Tags: python, base64

Uuencoding is historically used to encode emails. Instructions for creating a Uuencoder are:

1. Start with 3 bytes from the source, 24 bits in total.
2. Split into 4 6-bit groupings, each representing a value in the range 0 to 63: bits (00-05), (06-11), (12-17) and (18-23).
3. Add 32 to each of the values. With the addition of 32 this means that the possible results can be between 32 (" " space) and 95 ("_" underline). 96 ("`" grave accent) as the "special character" is a logical extension of this range.
4. Output the ASCII equivalent of these numbers.

```
import platform

def dec_to_bin(int):
    return bin(int).replace('0b', '')

def uuencode(string, filename):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        mode = '644'
    elif platform.system() == 'Linux':
        mode = '744'

    trail = 'begin ' + mode + ' ' + filename + '\n'
    string_values = []
    char_list = list(string)
    bytes = ''

    for char in char_list:
        string_values.append(ord(char))

    for ascii in string_values:
        bytes += dec_to_bin(ascii)

    three_byte = [bytes[p:p+24] for p in range(0, len(bytes), 24)]
    if len(three_byte[-1]) < 24:
        three_byte[-1] += (24 - len(three_byte[-1])) * '0'

    four_six_bits = [three_byte[n][m:m+6] for n in range(len(three_byte)) for m in range(0, 24, 6)]
    four_six_bits = [four_six_bits[k:k+4] for k in range(0, len(four_six_bits), 4)]

    decimal_list = []
    for x in range(len(four_six_bits)):
        for z in range(4):
            decimal_list.append(int(four_six_bits[x][z], 2))

    for index, decimal in enumerate(decimal_list):
        decimal_list[index] += 32

    encoded_chars = [chr(decimal_list[o]) for o in range(len(decimal_list))]

    length_char = chr(len(encoded_chars) + 32)
    trail += length_char

    for newchar in encoded_chars:
        trail += newchar

    trail += '\n' + '`' + '\n' + 'end' + '\n'

    return trail
```

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhat unstructured, but here are a few recommendations:

#### Be careful when shadowing built-ins

In `dec_to_bin()`, the `int` parameter shadows the Python core `int` type keyword. This works fine, but it's usually clearer to avoid redefining builtins when you can. Maybe call it `num`.

`bytes` is also a builtin. It's ok to redefine them, just be aware.

#### Variables not always defined

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    mode = '644'
elif platform.system() == 'Linux':
    mode = '744'

trail = 'begin ' + mode + ' ' + filename + '\n'
```

What happens if `platform.system()` is neither Windows or Linux? (For example: on Mac it returns `'Darwin'`.) `mode` will be undefined, raising `UnboundLocalError`.

#### Unnecessary conversion to list

```
char_list = list(string)
...
for char in char_list: ...
```

Strings are iterable just like lists, so `for char in string:` works fine.

In fact, consider removing `string_values` and `char_list` entirely. You can condense them into:

```
bytes = ''.join(dec_to_bin(ord(char)) for char in string)
```

#### Unused variable

A common convention is to use `_` to represent unused vars:

```
for index, _ in enumerate(decimal_list):
    decimal_list[index] += 32
```

This shows that you are deliberately ignoring the second value from `enumerate`.

Answer (score 3):

@BenC humbly mentioned en-passing that that his answer is *"somewhat unstructured"*, but while his answer is fine, I feel that this concern of lack  of structure applies to your code.

Your code encapsulates all the logic in one function (apart from a tiny helper), this is hard to test, hard to write and hard to read.

This algorithm lends itself pretty well to modularization: the same transformation is applied identical to each chunk of 3 bytes of the original message.

Each function can be equipped with a docstring describing its purpose, a link to further documentation and some examples improving readability.

My version of this `uuencode_chunk` also makes use of the chunks function (taken from StackOverflow) to divide the complexity further and because this chunk logic is necessary in two places:

```
import doctest

def padded_decimal_to_bin(i):
    return (bin(i).replace('0b', '')).rjust(8, "0")

def chunks(l, n):
    """
    Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    Credit to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

    >>> list(chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2))
    [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
    """
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def uuencode_chunk(chunk):
    """
    Given a chunk of 3 bytes (24 bits),
    splits it in 4 equal groups of 6, adds 32 to each
    and represents them as ASCII characters.

    See this section for details:
      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Formatting_mechanism

    >>> uuencode_chunk("Cat")
    '0V%T'
    """
    bits = [padded_decimal_to_bin(ord(char)) for char in chunk]
    return ''.join(chr(int(b, base=2) + 32) for b in chunks(''.join(bits), 6))

doctest.testmod()
```

Making use of the `uuencode_chunk` and `chunks` the main function should result much shorter and simpler.

Comment: I actually meant that my _answer_ would be somewhat unstructured. But this is a fantastic simplification of the code, nice.

Comment: @BenC I already had my idea that the code could be more organized than it was, so when reading your answer I just  took it to confirm my feeling, a fun coincidence, I am adapting the first paragraph of my answer.